use sed group variable within loop for another grep
Context: grep on result of sed grouping, within a loop
grep "blah" x.txt | sed 's/cheese\(.*\)/xlogs\/butter\1.log/g' | while read -r line; do
 echo $line; 
 //TODO: grep -r "$1" another_file.txt
done

above code works, to replace cheese123 with xlogs/butter123.log, retaining 123 variable, over the result of blah search. All good.
I want to use the captured 123 in the grouping, for another grep in another file, in the loop. Say even echo $1 aka 123 would suffice.
How do I do that, thanks in advance.

why do you use -r grep option when you are only searching a single file each time?

@jhnc, sure not required; but doesnt affect my problem/solution in any ways, right. Any solution for original question please..

it's easier to understand code that is not misleading - -r tells the reader you are trying to search recursively; if you don't mean that, it's better not to write it

Got it, corrected.

One option is to output two lines:
grep "blah" x.txt |
sed -n 's/cheese\(.*\)/xlogs\/butter\1.log\n\1/p' |
while IFS= read -r line1 && IFS= read -r line2; do
   echo "$line1"
   # TODO: grep "$line2" another_file.txt
done

To avoid the output getting out of sync if the sed command doesn't make any substitution, -n and s///p are used so that no output is produced in that case.
s///g flag is not needed since there can be only one match on a line.
The first grep could also be part of the sed:
sed -n '/blah/s/cheese\(.*\)/xlogs\/butter\1.log\n\1/p' x.txt |
while ...


@edmorton reminded me that using \n in replacement text is non-standard and not accepted by all implementations of sed (it may just turn into n). A newline can be inserted literally if preceded by a backslash (ensure there is no trailing whitespace):
| sed -n 's/cheese\(.*\)/xlogs\/butter\1.log\
\1/p' |

or in a more convoluted way like:
| sed -n 'G; s/cheese\(.*\)\(.\)/xlogs\/butter\1.log\2\1/p' |


worked! Thanks @jhnc

One issue though: 123 (or integer variable value, which is of my interest/question) is alternatively in line1 and in line2. Wonder why, any fix other than put a counter?

that shouldn't be possible. check the input doesn't have dos line endings. \r can produce confusing output. you'll need to provide sample input lines that can be used to reproduce your symptoms to determine for sure what is happening

OKies, will check and get back may be tomorrow. Neverthless thanks a ton for this, really appreciate this.

The reason for alternate values in line1 and line2 seems to be, there is actually 2 lines per grep result. When I streamline grep result to just one line (by deleting second line), it works. But then I cant delete the second line since it has some more data that I actually need. So, Iam thinking of putting a counter and swap lines per the count.

Having \n in the replacement text is undefined behavior per POSIX so different seds will do different things with it. It'll do what you want in GNU sed though so if you need that anyway you could also add -E and use a different delimiter to remove all the non-backreference escapes: sed -En 's:cheese(.*):xlogs/butter\1.log\n\1:p'

@EdMorton good point. I always forget about that even though bsd sed doesn't accept it

Thanks guys, these helped me do some quick post-processing!

grep piped to sed piped to a shell read loop calling grep is an antipattern, see https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.
This, untested, might be something like what you're trying to do (using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match()):
awk '
    NR == 1 {
        if ( /blah/ && match($0,/(.*)cheese(.*)/,a) ) {
            res[a[2]]
            print a[1] "xlogs/butter" a[2] ".log"
        }
        next
    }
    {
        for ( re in res ) {
            if ( $0 ~ re ) {
                print
                next
            }
        }
    }
' x.txt another_file.txt

but it's just a guess given no sample input and expected output in the question that we could test it with.
